# How to get JList to display ArrayList?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, jlist

I'm trying to get a Jlist to display a list of my own Client objects. My Client class DOES have a toString() method which works fine with System.out.print(), and I'm not sure where else my problem could lie.

Here is my code:

```
private void displayClients(){
    List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>(this.gym.getClients());
    displayClientsList.setListData(clients);
    displayClientsList.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
no suitable method found for setListData(List<Client>)
method JList.setListData(String[]) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; List<Client> cannot be converted to String[])
method JList.setListData(Vector<? extends String>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; List<Client> cannot be converted to Vector<? extends String>)
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: you cannot convert client to string that easy

Answer (score 2):

The API documents for this method says that it takes a Vector, or an array...

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setListData(E[])

Try...

```
displayClientsList.setListData(clients.toArray(new Client[0]));
```

Or you might want to make a list of strings yourself and show those, for example...

```
List<String> displayList = clients.stream()
    .map(c -> c.toString())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

displayClientsList.setListData(displayList.toArray(new String[0]));
```

Comment: You might need to change the generic type of the JList to String (not sure how you initialised it...)

Comment: Your second example has the same problem as the code in the question:  you can’t pass a plain List to the setListData method.  You would need to change it to `.collect(Collectors.toCollection(Vector::new))`, and change the type of displayList to `Vector<String>`.

Comment: @VGR Oops, sorry - fixing

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be like this:

```
List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>(this.gym.getClients());
String[] clientArray = new String[clients.size()];
displayClientsList.setListData(clients.toArray(clientArray));
```

Update:
The `JList` gets as a parameter a `String` array, so you need to firstly convert your clients list to a `String` array like this:

```
String[] clientAarray = clients.stream().map(c -> c.toString()).toArray(size -> new String[size]);
displayClientsList.setListData(clientArray);
```

Comment: Thanks, but the line 2 of your solution gives me this error:

Suspicious Collection.toArray() call. Collection item type gymcore.Client is not assignable to array component type java.lang.String

I guess this is a similar problem :S

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change `displayClientsList` from a `JList<String>` to a `JList<Client>` and then do the following:

```
    List<Client> clients = this.gym.getClients();
    displayClientsList.setListData(clients.toArray(new Client[clients.size()]));
```